# Как с помощью UPDATE (mysql) прибавить число к числу

Tags: php, mysql

Как при обновлении в таблице строки не перезаписать ее а добавить к ней значения.

Написал вот такой вот код PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['wallet']) && isset($_POST['adwalet']) && isset($_POST['myid'])){
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";
    
    $addwallet = $_POST['adwalet'];
    $myadwallet = $_POST['myid'];
    
    $wallet = $_POST['wallet'];
    $mywallet = $_POST['mywallet'];
    
    $walleter = $mywallet - $wallet;
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sqli = "UPDATE cl_users SET wallet='$walleter' WHERE id='$myadwallet'";
    $sql = "UPDATE cl_users SET `wallet`='$wallet'  WHERE adwallet='$addwallet'";
    
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    
    if ($conn->query($sqli) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
    
    $conn->close();
}
```

Вот это строка

```
$sqli = "UPDATE cl_users SET wallet='$walleter' WHERE id='$myadwallet'";
```

Когда пользователь отправляет форму с его баланса списывается определенная сумма.

А вот эта строка должна второму пользователю добавлять баланс

```
$sql = "UPDATE cl_users SET `wallet`='$wallet'  WHERE adwallet='$addwallet'";
```

Но заместо того что бы добавить число, происходить перезапись числа.

Пробовал еще вот такой вариант

```
$sql = "UPDATE cl_users SET `wallet`='wallet' + $wallet  WHERE adwallet='$addwallet'";
```

Но тоже не работает.

Суть этого кода такова

Пользователь 1 отправил пользователю 2, 50 монет.
У первого пользователя списало 50 монет а второму произошло начисление.

Но у меня получилось корректно работа только у первого пользователя, у второго постоянно обновляется значение а не прибоваляется.

Буду очень рад вашей помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Суть этого кода такова
>
> Пользователь 1 отправил пользователю 2, 50 монет. У первого пользователя списало 50 монет а второму произошло начисление.

Всё это должно делаться ОДНИМ запросом.

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET balance = CASE WHEN user = $sender   THEN balance - $amount
                   WHEN user = $receiver THEN balance + $amount
                   ELSE balance
                   END
WHERE user IN ($sender, $receiver);
```

Comment: Это шикарно, спасибо за помощь